# Magento 2.1.5 Tracking information is currently not available using UPS shipping method

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, shipment-tracking, ups

> I have installed a shipping tracker module and configured the UPS
> shipping method on Magento 2.1.5 local. The module with the same
> tracking id is working in other version but not in the Magento
> 2.1.5. I'm getting this in the debug.log file

```
[2021-05-21 06:19:38] main.DEBUG: array (
  'request' => '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<AccessRequest xml:lang="en-US">
  <AccessLicenseNumber>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</AccessLicenseNumber>
  <UserId>xxxxxxx</UserId>
  <Password>xxxxxxx</Password>
</AccessRequest><?xml version="1.0" ?>
<TrackRequest xml:lang="en-US">
    <Request>
        <RequestAction>Track</RequestAction>
        <RequestOption>activity</RequestOption>
    </Request>
    <TrackingNumber>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</TrackingNumber>
    <IncludeFreight>01</IncludeFreight>
</TrackRequest>',
  'result' => '',
) {"is_exception":false} []
```

**Note that I have replaced the real credentials with XXXXXXXXX.**

In the backend, when clicking on track this shipment it shows no tracking details as shown in the below screenshot,

[image: screensho1]

**I have also checked on the ups site to track details which are completely fine. Please let me know if anyone has any ideas.**

### EDIT

> shipping_tracking_popup.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="empty" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Shipping\Block\Tracking\Popup" name="shipping.tracking.popup1" template="Vendor_Module::tracking/popup.phtml"/>
            <referenceBlock name="shipping.tracking.popup" remove="true" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> popup.phtml

```
$results = $block->getTrackingInfo();
```

I'm getting `$results` as shown in the below screenshot,

[image: Screenshot3]

> I have checked in the `Magento\Shipping\Block\Tracking\Popup` class, by echoing `$info->getTrackingInfo()` shows same as the above screenshot.
>
> Magento\Shipping\Block\Tracking\Popup.php

```
  /**
     * Retrieve array of tracking info
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getTrackingInfo()
    {
        /* @var $info \Magento\Shipping\Model\Info */
        $info = $this->_registry->registry('current_shipping_info');

        return $info->getTrackingInfo();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There was no issue in the code.

In `Stores -> Configuration -> Sales -> Shipping Methods`

> Under UPS, in Tracking XML URL field,

before it was set as,

https://wwwe.ups.com/ups.app/xml/Track

changed to,

https://wwwcie.ups.com/ups.app/xml/Track

**Now it's working. This issue is only in Magento 2.1**

Comment: I had Magento 246p1 , entered this as XML URL : https://onlinetools.ups.com/ups.app/xml/Track

still not showing tracking information,can you please help ?